# Spark Xml read including filename

Tags: xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use spark-xml like below to read all files in a folder:

```
val df = sparkSession
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .option("rootTag", "Transactions")
  .option("rowTag", "Transaction")
  .load("/Users/spark/Desktop/sample")
```

And inside the sample folder, there are X amount of xml files.

base on the customSchema I provided, each file will become 1..n rows base on the # of transaction tags. But what I want is also to include the xml file name as an extra column with each record.

I searched the spark-xml github options but seems no ideal results.

Please give suggestions or maybe I could achieve the goal using a different method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Use the sql function input_file_name. In your case it should be something like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfWithFile = df.withColumn("file",input_file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input_file_name()` function and do it at the time of reading by chaining this function after the load option using withColumn.

```
val df = sparkSession
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .option("rootTag", "Transactions")
  .option("rowTag", "Transaction")
  .load("/Users/spark/Desktop/sample")
  .withColumn("FileName",input_file_name())
```

Comment: This is explaining properly and it is working solving the issue.

Comment: Is there any idea if we want to add the last modified date/time also as a column into the df

Comment: you can just do that using withColumn but how are you getting that info?